# How to select a file or directory and drag it while scrolling rapidly?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

I am using Gnome-desktop in Ubuntu 19.10, but I had similar experiences with 18.04, 18.10, and 19.04.

Sometimes I want to select some files in a window (i.e. in a Files/Natilus window), and move them to a sub-directory. There are sometimes many other files in the same directory as those I am selecting, and the sub-directory might be, for example, at the end of the list of files.

How can I scroll down the list of files while dragging my selection? The two-finger swipe on my touchpad, which would scroll for me with nothing selected, does not work.

If I hover the tip of the pointer near the top or bottom edge of the window while files are selected, I can scroll through the list, but this is ***very slow***. Is there any way to do this with a touchpad gesture which provides a rapid scrolling through the files?

Answer (score -1):

Drag it just bellow the toolbar and it will start scrolling.

The closer you are to the toolbar - faster it scrolls.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You may not have noticed that I described this as ***very slow*** in my question. I have edited to clarify that I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: when you approach the border it accelerates, when you go in the other direction it slows down

Comment: Nope, not past ***very slow*** (by comparison to two-finger scrolling with no selection) it doesn't.